# spicework error "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT"

Tags: spiceworks

I installed the spicework window setup on my server 2008. Here is the URL http://ffrsdevserver.com:9675/portal for my dev server. It works fine on my(Indian) system, other systems of my company, my mobile device with 3G network.
My client in USA said it not worked for him. I verify this by login to server located in USA. on server's browser i got error `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` Can anybody suggest how can i fix it, I searched a lot on google and spicework community but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my port 9675 was closed. I open the port and it fix my problem. Thanks :)